# Jquery easyui tabs and tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, tree

I am using jQuery easyui tabs and adding a new tab panel using code.

```
var index = 0;

function add() {
    index++;
    window.iddd=index;
    var title='Job-'+index;

    $('#tt').tabs('add', {
        id:'tabb'+index,
        title:title,
        href:'lcm.jsp',
        closable: true
    });
}
```

and in the lcm.jsp I have jQuery easyui tree. I am initializing tree when user add a new tabs like

```
$('#'+$('#'+tablayout.container+' div#'+tablayout.region_west+' ul').attr('id')).tree({
    onCheck:function(node) {
        alert("treeeee");
        var nodes = $('#'+$('#'+tablayout.container+' div#'+tablayout.region_west+' ul').attr('id')).tree('getChecked');
        for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
            var children = $('#'+$('#'+tablayout.container+' div#'+tablayout.region_west+' ul').attr('id')).tree('getParent', nodes[i].target);
            alert('#'+this.id);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that it works fine when i add 1st tab in tabs panel. on clicking tree node i get the alert. but when i add the  2nd tab, tree is loaded but i do not get alert on clicking its tree node. however 1st tabs still work fine and i get the alert when i click tree node in 1st tab only.

Thanks in advance.